# Show a message, if file is not existing in the working directory in Shiny

Tags: message, shiny-server

I am new to R as well as to Shiny.
I would like to display a message "File not existing" , in shiny main panel, if a.csv file is not there in the working directory. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: you should show us what code you have written

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
library(shiny)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # Listens for click from element with ID=chck_file
  observeEvent(input$chck_file,{
    # Check if file exists
    if ( file.exists( isolate({input$fname}) ) ){
      # Display text
      output$text <- renderText({ paste("File exists in: ",getwd(),sep="") })
    }
    else{
      output$text <- renderText({ paste("No such file in: ",getwd(),sep="") })
    }
  })

  # Listens for click from element with ID=create_file
  observeEvent(input$create_file,{
    # Create file
    file.create(isolate({input$fname}))
  })
})

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  textInput("fname","File name: ",value="myfile.txt"),
  verbatimTextOutput("text"),
  actionButton("chck_file", "Check for file"),
  actionButton("create_file", "Create file")
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```